# Vue $refs and kebab case

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In vue 1 it was possible to do this:

```
<app v-ref:test-app></app>
```

and then reference it like so:

```
vm.$refs.testApp;
```

however in vue 2 the syntax for the ref has changed to:

```
<app ref="test-app"></app>
```

but this no longer can be referenced by

```
vm.$refs.testApp
```

instead it only works if:

```
<app ref="testApp"></app>
```

which in standard DOM stuff isn't allowed. Is it a bug? can kebab case no longer be used?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since the syntax has been changed from that of a namespaced element attribute (i.e., `v-ref:foo-bar`) to a normal key-value-pair attribute (i.e., `ref="fooBar"`), the implicit kebab-case-to-camel-case conversion is no longer applicable because the reference name is a plain string and is not constrained by having to conform to the requisite lowercase-kebab-case HTML syntax.

In other words, you can identify a ref with any string, so it wouldn't make sense for Vue to manipulate it. Have a look at this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLEOZx?editors=1012) for an example in action of what I mean.

But, basically, a plain string ref value means you can define a reference like this:

```
<div id="app" ref="test ** app!"></div>
```

and reference it from Vue like this:

```
this.$refs['test ** app!']
```

In short, no, it's not a bug but no, automatic kebab-case conversion no longer takes place.