# ArangoDB + JSON + Vue nomenclature: what problems might I encounter if I use kebab-case everywhere?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, arangodb

I am a beginner. I am working on a project for myself that uses ArangoDB, Node.js, Javascript and Vue. I am trying to decide on a nomenclature / style guide for my project. I believe it will be confusing to try to maintain different styles in my codebase for each different part of the technology stack. Therefore, I am inclined to use kebab-case everywhere.

For example, I am confused by the mix of `MyComponent` and `my-component` in the "good" example in the [Vue style guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/).

```
Vue.component('MyComponent', {
  // ...
})

Vue.component('my-component', {
  // ...
})

import MyComponent from './MyComponent.vue'

export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  // ...
}
```

While researching this question, I came across the [following statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41226217/10783877):

> the implicit kebab-case-to-camel-case conversion is no longer applicable because the reference name is a plain string and is not constrained by having to conform to the requisite lowercase-kebab-case HTML syntax

I do not understand what that means and until now I had not heard of "implicit kebab-case-to-camel-case conversion" even though I have watched a couple Vue tutorials. Several searches have failed to bring up any explicit discussion of Vue's implicit kebab-case conversation for me.

Obviously, there is more to the decision about kebab-case vs Pascal-case than I understand and I need to seek out advice from experienced developers before I make a decision.

Another way to ask this would be:

1. Is there any technology-related issue that will prevent me from using kebab-casing for JSON?
2. Are there **implicit** rules (especially for Vue projects) that could get me into trouble if I use kebab-case everywhere?

I hope it is obvious that this isn't an opinion-based question. What I would like to know is what unexpected problems might I run into if I try to use kebab-case everywhere in a project that uses ArangoBB, Node.js, Javascript and Vue?

Update: The Vue Style Guide says, "**using kebab-case everywhere is also acceptable**." (But it is not clear to me what "everywhere" means in this context.

In searching further, I found a good discussion here which seems to disagree with that statement from the Vue style guide: [HTML case sensitivity workaround · Issue #2308 · vuejs/vue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2308)

> Essentially, the problem exists because javascript and HTML are different
> technologies and use different naming systems. And using same
> case (kebab or camel) in both technologies will shift weirdness from
> one place to another but the underlying problem will persist.
>
> I believe, best we can do is draw a line, and the current line is very good:
>
> 1. kebab case in html context
> 2. camelCase (and PascalCase) in javascript context .
>
> IMO, we should just support current conventions instead of looking
> for a better one. And of course, use warning to help beginners.

It seems most responses agreed with that. The last response was:

> The one rule to commit to memory: HTML = kebab-case, JavaScript =
> camelCase
>
> By HTML I mean attributes and tags. Attribute values are JavaScript
> expressions when you use v-bind, so the second statement applies.

But my question remains: What unexpected problems might I run into if I try to **use kebab-case everywhere** in a project that uses ArangoBB, Node.js, Javascript and Vue?